# Flutter - How to scale and draw over image in custompainter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to draw over image on custompainter. I am using the example on [flutter custompainter video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvI_NUXK00s) and here is what I have so far. I can draw in the image but I cannot scale image. How do I scale image on gesture and draw in image? I would prefer not to use any package.

```
Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.black87,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onScaleStart: _scaleStartGesture,
                onScaleUpdate: _scaleUpdateGesture,
                onScaleEnd: (_) => _scaleEndGesture(),
                child: SizedBox(
                    height: _image.height.toDouble(),
                    width: _image.width.toDouble(),
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      willChange: true,
                      painter: ImagePainter(
                        image: _image,
                        points: points 
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ),
```

Comment: Use InteractiveViewer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html. It’s bundled with flutter.

Comment: I did. If I use interactiveViewer I cannot use pan gestures because pan gestures moves scale images in axes and doesn't record gesture. Besides I already have a gesturedetector and nesting two gesture detector is a big no no already. Ignorepointer didn't help as well.

Comment: How about warping your image widget on Transform.Scale and controlling the scale value with the same GestureDetector you are using.

Comment: why you don't try to use icon buttons for each scaling and drawing,isn't better way?

Comment: IconButton for scaling would only be one dimensional scaling. It doesn't give much freedom needed to zoom into a part of image and work on that.

Comment: I did try that but the globalposition doesn't change accordingly. And also, zooming to specific part and drawing works but on zooming out canvas points don't zoom out.  Best case would be if I was able to use InteractiveViewer for scaling and normal gesturedetector for drawing.

Comment: The source code inside `InteractiveViewer` use `Transform` & `GestureDetector` to do the scaling effect. If you think the scale effect from  `InteractiveViewer` is enough for you, I think you should check how it implement.

Comment: I cannot use pan effect from interactiveviewer while using gesture detector. And using onInteractionStart etc. on interactiveViewer itself doesn't work when scaled because it just moves around the image and doesn't record any gesture or atleast it is choppy.  InteractiveViewer code isn't exactly straightforward, otherwise I would have implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Merge `LongPressDraggable` or `Draggable` and GestureDetector's onScaleUpdate;

```
onScaleUpdate: (s) {
             
                    if (!(s.scale == 1 && s.rotation == 0)) {
                      controller
                        ..setImageRotate(s.rotation)
                        ..setImageScale(s.scale)
                        ..setImageOffset(s.focalPoint);
                      setState(() {
                        message = controller.selectedController.toString();
                      });
                   
                  }
                },
```

Controller Class ;

```
final StreamController<ImageController> _controllerStreamController =
      StreamController<ImageController>.broadcast();
  Stream<ImageController> get controllerTypeStream =>
      _controllerStreamController.stream;

  double rotateSync;
  void setImageRotate(double rotate) {
    if (selectedController == null) {
       rotateSync = rotate;
      _controllerStreamController.sink.add(this);
    }
  }

  Offset offset;
  void setImageOffset(Offset rotate) {
    if (selectedController == null) {
      offset = rotate;
      _controllerStreamController.sink.add(this);
    }
  }
  double scaleSync;    
  void setImageScale(double scale) {
    if (selectedController == null) {
      scaleSync = scale;
      _controllerStreamController.sink.add(this);
    }
  }
```

And than set image widget in 'Stack' widget ;

Stack -> GestureDetector -> Draggable -> Transform.scale -> Transform.translate -> Tranform.rotate -> SizedBox(ImageWidget)

Comment: I am converting image to ui.image right now. So I don't need stack I guess. I also don't need rotate. While scaling there is two problems right now. 
1. Scaled image goes out of bounds.
2. I cannot find scale focal point.